# "varietal" vs. "various" vs. "varied"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, non-standard, disambiguities, dialectal

Please, consider the following sourced excerpts:

> *An ideal romantic daytime date might be to pack a blanket and take your lady to Old Town Silverdale. Settled in 1854, this beautiful little town port offers **varietal** amenities — the Kitsap Mall, movie theatres, and a variety of nice restaurants.*
>
> [KitsapSun](http://www.kitsapsun.com/lifestyle/john-kurt----a-romantic-date-in-old-town-ep-420833614-358087191.html)
>
> *Green Mountain Orchards is in Putney, Vermont...a lovely little quirky hamlet with such **varietal** attractions as the bizarre Santa’s Land and the cult favorite the Putney Diner...not to mention the thoroughly awesome Putney Co-op.*
>
> [We Have the Mini...We Just Need the Van](https://ieatoats.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/laborless-weekend/)
>
> *In this season of giving thanks, we want to extend a giant thank you
>   to all of our volunteers who have expressed interest in helping with our **varietal** activities this year!*
>
> [Tope Elementary School](http://tope.mesa.k12.co.us/news/documents/TopeTimesNov2009.pdf)

Shouldn't it be ***various*** in the first two examples and ***varied*** (or ***various***) in the last, rather than ***varietal***?

Also, could you please explain to me how interchanging ***varied***, ***various***, and ***varietal***, as in these other sourced examples, makes the meaning of a phrase different?

> *Our staff come from **varied** ethnic backgrounds.* 
>   [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/varied)
>
> *Our staff come from **various** ethnic backgrounds.*
>
> *Our staff come from [**varietal**](http://www.bestvippatients.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=607&Itemid=518) ethnic backgrounds.*

-and-

> *Suggestions were numerous and **varied**.*
>
> *Suggestions were numerous and **various**.* [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/various)
>
> *Suggestions were numerous and [**varietal**](http://enargea.org/janus/2_faces.html).* [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=varietal+rooms&biw=681&bih=447&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3jIuy4NzLAhVH7RQKHfsxA-4Q_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22numerous+and+varietal%22)

VARIETAL

> *adj.*  of a specific variety
>
> [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/varietal)
>
> :  of, relating to, or characterizing a variety : *varietal names*; also :  being a variety in distinction from an individual or species
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/varietal)

Comment: 'Varietal' meaning 'pertaining to [different] varieties [of a grape say] is correct for the second example (if a little strange-sounding). The other two examples are non-standard, though this may not have been the case in 1854.

Comment: "Our staff come from a varietal ethnic background."  Would be correct, and would mean we're all from the same ethnic background.